# Persistent orange dot (microphone) icon even when microphone not in actual use - how to find out which app may be causing this?

Tags: audio, privacy, microphone, monterey, control-center

I've been having some strange issues where the "orange dot" (microphone supposedly active/on/listening/recording), but I have no visible apps that actually *should* have the microphone active.

Is there a way to query the system to find out what apps are accessing such devices as the microphone from the shell or otherwise? I would very much like to find out what app is "needing" to use the microphone for days and weeks on end...

Comment: When you click control center icon with the orange dot, does it show at the top of that window?

Comment: @Ezekiel no. There's no app or anything there about what app might be supposedly using the microphone(s).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Micro Snitch](https://obdev.at/products/microsnitch/index.html) to monitor audio and video devices and to alert me whenever an application wants access.

There may be other products that do the same.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice and I also tried [OverSight](https://objective-see.com/products/oversight.html), but it also doesn't show anything. I will say Micro Snitch is better insomuch that it shows active + inactive devices and so it has more information readily visible. But yeah, unfortunately nothing is showing as active with either of these while the orange dot is present.